# Vim error : Error detected while processing function <SNR>14_UseConfigFiles[26]..<SNR>14_Initialize[47]..<SNR>14_InitializePythonBuiltin:

Tags: python, vim

I got the following error when I simply `$ vim CHANGELOG.md`

```
"CHANGELOG.md" 1788L, 61291C
Error detected while processing function <SNR>14_UseConfigFiles[26]..<SNR>14_Initialize[47]..<SNR>14_InitializePythonBuiltin:
line   23:
/must>not&exist/foo:1: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

[image]

Any idea where it come from ?
Can someone help me to debug this ?

Comment: I'm sure it's related to the issue: https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1925. The resolution is: this is a problem in vim, not Powerline. vim is not yet ready for Python 3.7.

Answer (score 17):

Do `:scriptnames`. Script number 14 is where the errors come from.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Python error somewhere that isn't trapped correctly by `s:InitializePythonBuiltin()` from your script 14 (check `:scriptnames` as romainl said). Either make sure the error doesn't happen any more, by no longer importing `imp`, or contact the maintainer of the plugin #14 to not complain on this deprecation problem, or to make his plugin portable...

Shameless plug: in lh-vim-lib, I provide a [`lh#exception#say_what()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/doc/Callstack.md) function that if called will permit you navigate the functions called in the context of the last error.

Answer (score 1):

I got this while rebasing in git. I ended up deleting the plugin directory that was not compiling properly for Python.

`rm -rf /Users/<username>/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe`

Updating the plugin to the latest version is also possible.